# Tiny bit of extra space around the JPanel when it should fill the JFrame

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, gridbaglayout

I've made an MRE which you can find at the bottom, as well as the image file I'm using. Not sure if it would have been better to just upload my src folder, but someone can let me know if that's okay to do.
First off, it does fill the JFrame. However there is a catch. It only fills properly when the contentpane dimensions are, I believe a multiple of 54. I have a picture attached, because it's a lot easier to see then it is to explain.

[image]

Now if I resize the `JFrame`. If I expand the width by one more pixel the  `JPanel` will fill horizontally. Same goes for the Height if I expand the JFrame Vertically by one more pixel the JPanel will fill vertically Like the image below.

[image]

The only difference between the two images is that I expanded the height/width of the JFrame by 1 more pixel in the second image

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;


class UIPanel extends JPanel {
    private BufferedImage[] textures;
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    JLayeredPane jp = new JLayeredPane();
    BufferedImage PewterCityMap;

    UIPanel() {
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        jp.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        c.fill = 1;
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        try {
            PewterCityMap = ImageIO.read(new File("src/imagesUI/PewterCityMap.jpg"));
            final int width = 16;
            final int height = 16;
            final int rows = 55;
            final int cols = 53;
            textures = new BufferedImage[rows * cols];

            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                    textures[(i * cols) + j] = PewterCityMap.getSubimage(
                            j * width, i * height,
                            width, height
                    );
                }
            }
        } catch (
                IOException ex) {
                  ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 55; i++) {
            c.gridy = i;
            c.gridx = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < 53; j++) {
                c.gridx = j;
                    CanEnterLbl canEnterLbl = new CanEnterLbl(new ImageIcon(textures[count]));
                    jp.add(canEnterLbl, c);
                    jp.setLayer(canEnterLbl, 0);
                count++;
            }
        }
        this.add(jp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        UIPanel ui = new UIPanel();
        jf.add(ui, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.pack();
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class CanEnterLbl extends JLabel{
    private Image img;
    CanEnterLbl(ImageIcon imageIcon){
        img = imageIcon.getImage();
        this.setIcon(imageIcon);
    }
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        //In reply to @Frakcool. 
        //Firstly, thank you! Are the next two lines what you were thinking? I 
        doesn't fill correctly when using just this line though 
        //super.paintComponent(g);
        //What I was doing before
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
    }
}
```

Here is the Image file I'm using. I would have used a publicly available image but the image's height & width need to be multiples of 16.
[image]

Comment: 1) Don't ignore stack traces, at the very minimum print them! They provide so much useful information for debugging. 2) You're breaking the paint chain, call `super.paintComponent()` on the `paintComponent` method. And its signature is `protected` not `public`

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the advice with the ```trycatch```. I've updated my ```trycatch```. Is that more so what the ideal ```catch``` should look like? I did make some changes to my code(locally) to try and use ```super.paintComponent(g)``` with ```repaint()``` but I couldn't get it to fill properly I'll upload what I did in a second. I appreciate your help! Do you have any idea why it leaves space on the sides though when resizing?

Comment: I never told you to include `repaint()` inside the `paintComponent`, that might create an infinite bucle.

Comment: Thank you! It doesn't fill the space in the ```JLabel``` though so do you know how I could get it to fill? Perhaps make the ```JLabels``` layout a ```GridBagLayout``` and set the ```constraint.fill = 1```? Something like that

Comment: I'm trying to figure it out.

Comment: Why are you doing custom painting for the label? By default the JLabel will paint the ImageIcon at its actual size. There is no need for custom painting.

Comment: @camickr The ```JLabels``` are in a ```GridBagLayout``` and resize with the ```JFrame``` I need the images to resize with the JLabel and the only way I know how is by using use ```g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);``` inside of ```paintComponent()```

Comment: @camickr Hello, thank you for your help. I decided to give up on trying to accomplish my goal of making it fit the frame. You were totally right, all the cells have the same width/height so in order to increase their width/height by one pixel there needs to be 53 pixels available horizontally or 55 vertically. I did notice however if I make all the components JButtons it does actually fit the frame! An absolute horrible solution! But perhaps it's possible to create a JButton class that removes all the unnecessary stuff from a button in order to accomplish getting it to fit the frame size...

Comment: @camickr ...the reason I even needed to do this in the first place was because the sprite sits on top of the gridbaglayout, not in it, and the map would move up to 26 pixels in height/width when resizing but the sprite would stay still. I ended up just coming up with a system that can detect which cell the sprite is on top of and set his location to the center of that cell when the frame gets resized. Thank you anyways!

Comment: @Bwizz *You were totally right* - then your question was answered and the answer should be "accepted" by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved. Whether you use a JLabel or a JButton doesn't matter. The labels will still fit the frame. There is no empty space when you pack the frame and display it. You only get the extra space when you resize the frame. You can prevent frame resizing if this is a problem.

Comment: @camickr I thought about that, but I thought moving the sprite could get tricky, but I guess something simple like this would have worked: ```if (sprite.movingRight ==true){ if (sprite.x == cell.width) {sprite.cell++; sprite.x = 0; }}``` would have worked. However, the collision detection works off the image/cell. You can see how I've sort of done things in this image https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jQ-YXTxRkuqIB2wK-bfUJ904wPTgwflC/view?usp=sharing   I have an edit mode where I turn all cells into buttons and when I click one, their cell number gets stored in a txt file that gets read ...

Comment: ... into an ```ArrayList``` when the program runs. When the images get added to the ```GridBagLayout``` like in the MRE above, all I need to do is ```if(ArrayList.contains(count){ //add collision box class}```. Idk if that's the best way, but I'm not sure how else I could've added the collision boxes so easily.

Comment: @camickr Also, I never noticed your comment from above _Whether you use a JLabel or a JButton doesn't matter._ I meant while resizing as well. Using JButtons instead of labels made it fit the frame somehow. My code has changed a lot from originally posting this MRE. You can see it fitting the frame here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nStEVnuaHqIt1ctUYyNk70VH1YMRE9-D/view?usp=sharing

Comment: *You can see it fitting the frame here* - When I run the code you originally posted the frame fits the images exactly. There is no empty space around the image. This is to be expected because you pack() the frame. *Using JButtons instead of labels made it fit the frame somehow.* - the layout manager doesn't know (or care) what components are being used. Using a JButton should not make a difference.

Comment: All the layout manager does is set the size/location of the component. This will not affect how the pack() method works. If you are experiencing different behaviour in your real code, then you have logic that you did not include in the code posted with your question that is causing the problem.

Comment: Your original question has been answered. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved.

Comment: @camickr Bruh I'm not talking about pack(). I literally mean when I resize the frame no matter what the size of the frame is, the JButtons fit the frame. Look at the second image you can see the buttons on the top and left get compressed.

Comment: I see the buttons shrink if I try to make the frame smaller after it has been packed, but once the frame is resized larger the gap comes back. In any case you have asked many questions in the forum and have not yet "accepted" an answer when you get help, so you are on your own.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you say. What matters is what the code does. The code you posted does NOT behave that way, so quit shouting. We can only help if we have the proper information. *The code I'm using is a tad bit different from the MRE though* - and that is my point. If we don't have the exact code that describes your problem then your verbal description of the problem is meaningless. We can only provide solutions based on the code we see.

Comment: @camickr I think your misunderstanding. I'm not saying it's a problem. Back in my original comment about it, I was just highlighting an interesting thing that occurred that fixed the problem in a very bad way. That is it. Nothing else.

Comment: You are not understanding what I am suggesting. You claim that you can get the GridBagLayout to resize components so that the components will always grow to the edge of the frame as the frame is resized larger. I don't believe it. This question has been asked before and I have never seen an answer to solve the problem. So if that statement is in fact true then you should give yourself credit for solving the problem and post your solution as the real answer, so others can learn how to do this. Otherwise, your statement is meaningless, because you can't prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need the images to resize

Then you should not use a JLabel to display the image. You don't need all the extra overhead of the JLabel UI.

Instead you can create a custom component by extending `JComponent`. Then you customize it's `paintComponent()` method to scale the image as it is drawn.

> It only fills properly when the contentpane dimensions are, I believe a multiple of 54.

I would guess a multiple of 53 horizontally and 55 vertically.

The `GridBagLayout` will first allocate space to each component at its preferred size.

Then if there is extra space it will allocate the space to each component based on the weightx/y constraint.

You can't allocate a fraction of a pixel to a component. So the best that can be done is to allocate a single pixel, which is why you need either 53 or 55 depending on the sizing direction.

I don't know of any layout manager in the JDK that can prevent the extra space around the panel edges

A possible solution is to use the [Relative Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/02/relative-layout/). The `Relative Layout` allows components to be sized relative to the space available. Once components are given there relative size it allows you to specify how "extra" pixels should be allocated.

To use this approach you would need a main panel that uses the `RelativeLayout` vertically, followed by child panels for each row that uses the `RelativeLayout` horizontally.

So the logic might be something like:

```
RelativeLayout verticalLayout = new RelativeLayout(RelativeLayout.Y_AXIS);
verticalLayout.setRoundingPolicy( RelativeLayout.EQUAL );
verticalLayout.setFill(true);
JPanel mapPanel = new JPanel( vertcalLayout );

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) 
{
    RelativeLayout rowLayout = new RelativeLayout(RelativeLayout.X_AXIS);
    rowLayout.setRoundingPolicy( RelativeLayout.EQUAL );
    rowLayout.setFill(true);

    JPanel row = new JPanel( rowLayout );

    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) 
    {
        CanEnterLbl canEnterLbl = new CanEnterLbl(…);
        row.add(canEnterLbl, new Float(1));
    }

    mapPanel.add(row, new Float(1));
}
```

Note, the RelativeLayout does not calculate an initial preferred size, so you would need to set that so the frame.pack() method works properly.